# Insert rows into mySQL table where target table has more columns

Tags: mysql, insert, replace

I have 2 tables. I want to replace rows in table 1 with the rows in table2.
However table 1 has more columns (appended after the common column names) so the following will not work...

```
replace into table1 select * from table2;
```

So I have to list all the column names ...

```
replace into table1 (col1, col2, ...) select col1, col2, ... from table2;
```

Is there a shortcut way to do something like this without actually listing all the columns?

Or is there a way to generate the column names from the table so I can go? ...

```
replace into table1 <list of columns that are in table2> 
    select <list of columns that are in table2> from table2;
```

Comment: How should the DBMS know, which columns to copy, if you don't specify them?

Comment: @feeela. I though it would just use the column order as it manages to do if there are the same number of columns in each table (I meant to say that the extra columns are appended to table1 after the common column names).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c,d)
SELECT field_that_becomes_a, null as becomes_b, field_that_becomes_c, 'static value' as becomes_d
FROM table2
```

Any fields you don't specify in table1 will simply assume their specified default values (or kill the query if there is no default).

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. The thing that I dont want to do is to explicitly list the columns. I.e. dont want to write (a,b,c,d)

Comment: That's the only way you'll be able to guarantee things go into the right place. Otherwise you might as well stand 500 yards back and use a catapult. Maybe some data will go into the right place, eventually.

Comment: @Mark-B, if this is the case then please dont propose a solution when the solution doesn't answer the question at all - this just adds to the confusion.